# Ubuntu: LDAP Invalid Credentials

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, ubuntu-12.04

I posted this question after tried solutions from google and stackoverflow. I am using ubuntu 12.04.

I installed ldap and slapd in my machine. On installation , it prompted for admin password.

After installation , I tried to add an kerberos schema using this below command,

```
ldapadd  -x -D cn=admin,cn=config -W -f /tmp/cn\=kerberos.ldif
```

It throws an error

```
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

I can able to use this command with my admin password.

```
ldapadd  -x -D "cn=admin,dc=zmedia,dc=ultrasound,dc=com" -f tree.ldif  -W
```

**tree.ldif**

```
#Sample LDAP File


#users

dn: ou=users,dc=zmedia,dc=ultrasound,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: users

#groups

dn: ou=groups,dc=zmedia,dc=ultrasound,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: groups
```

I know , I gave correct password. But , I dont know why it fails?

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, your bind DN (the -D option) is:
`-D cn=admin,cn=config`

In your second example, your bind DN is:
`"cn=admin,dc=zmedia,dc=ultrasound,dc=com"`

I do not think the double quotes matter.  But regardless, those are two different users.  A DN is unique within a directory service, so it would make sense that only one user works, since it is most likely you only have one real Admin user.

Comment: @bharathi  "Error 49" is not working fine.  You said, binding with a -D setting of cn=admin,cn=config, gives an error.  But it works when you use the otehr Admin account.  Where did you say it was working fine?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your root account has a password (default for Ubuntu is none). Adding a schema is done under root permissions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem on my old LinuxMint 20 :

```
ldapadd -x -D cn=admin,dc=phoebe -W -f share/ehome/ldap/init.ldif
```

I'm not sure in which domain the admin has been declared. As I install ldap for test purpose on my laptop, I do not really have a complete host name (+ domain).

The result is the same: bad credential.

NOTE: at installation time, apt asked me to enter the admin password (but no idea of the domain).